# Compilation error with cpp in R

Tags: r, clang, rcpp

I recently "upgraded" to XCode 5.2 and now a number of R packages will not work. I have a 15" MBP running OSX Mavericks 10.9.1 and am running R 3.0.2.

First, the mcmc function in the package diversitree broke and gave the following error:

```
Error in .External(list(name = "CppMethod__invoke_notvoid", address = <pointer: 0x0>,  : 
  NULL value passed as symbol address
```

Furthermore, I cannot compile the package "geomorph" from source, and I get the following error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'SHLIB_LIBADD'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '='
make: *** [geomorph.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘geomorph’
```

So I believe the error is somewhere in the compilers. I tested this idea with:

```
> require(Rcpp)
> evalCpp("1+1")
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include  -I"/Users/Chris/Library/R/3.0/library/Rcpp/include"    -fPIC  "-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion" -c file177c642d0b53.cpp -o file177c642d0b53.o clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o sourceCpp_1783.so file177c642d0b53.o /Users/Chris/Library/R/3.0/library/Rcpp/lib/libRcpp.a SHLIB_LIBADD = -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation 
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, showOutput = showOutput,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.

WARNING: The tools required to build C++ code for R were not found.

Please install Command Line Tools for XCode (or equivalent).

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'SHLIB_LIBADD'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '='
make: *** [sourceCpp_1783.so] Error 1
```

Also this:

```
has_devel()
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --vanilla  \
  CMD SHLIB foo.c 

clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  "-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion" -c foo.c -o foo.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o foo.so foo.o SHLIB_LIBADD = -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'SHLIB_LIBADD'
Error: Command failed (1)
clang: error: no such file or directory: '='
make: *** [foo.so] Error 1
```

I tried reinstalling Rcpp from source and that fails too:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'SHLIB_LIBADD'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '='
make: *** [Rcpp.so] Error 1
```

I've spent hours now trying to troubleshoot this and I've run across numerous mentions of editing the Makeconf file to add clang. I have done this but still cannot get things that use C in R to work. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: That question has been addressed a number of times here. Set CC and CXX to something which exists on your machine (as the new OS X in in disagreement with the existing R configuration).  Then rebuild packages from source.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did state in the last section of the question that I did edit the Makeconf file and I still have the problem. I changed them to clang and clang++ respectively.

Comment: I am not an OS X user. I'd say try the r-sig-mac list.  From what you state here something is still amiss but I can't help you much further.  Start with something simple (eg package 'digest', just C), then Rcpp, and so on.

Comment: Thanks again. I noticed that one common theme was the 'SHLIB_LIBADD' error, so I changed that in the Makeconf file to 
    -L/usr/lib/R/lib

This allowed for most of the packages to compile but I still have issues. I'll ask the r-sig-mac list.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a CRAN-provided binary of R, or your own compiled version of R? Did you compile R with your new XCode compilers or the old ones?

My experience is that CRAN-R will work fine with a specific compiler toolchain, as long as you use *the same toolchain* for all the packages you compile. If you, for example, try to link a new-XCode compiled package to an old-XCode compiled Rcpp, you will have problems.

Your `SHLIB_LIBADD` error, as far as I can guess, says you did something weird in your `Makevars` or `Makeconf` and now things are going wrong in parsing the files. I'd be curious to see if you can reproduce this with a fresh, CRAN-provided R.

Can you reproduce the problem if you try to re-install R + all your packages? You should try re-installing R with a fresh library directory, and then re-installing these problematic packages, and going from there.

Comment: I did a complete wipe of everything R on my computer and reinstalled from binary. That fixed most of my issues but I still have one problem running the mcmc function from the "diversitree" package:

    Error in .External(list(name = "CppMethod__invoke_notvoid", address =     <pointer: 0x0>,  : 
  NULL value passed as symbol address

Comment: Hmm... any chance you can post a small, reproducible example? I can try running it and let you know if I get a similar error. Maybe post it as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and I can try to run it.